# Select from two column by two dates in codeignter models

Tags: codeigniter, select, model

I want to select from two column with two dates given in codeigniter models.

```
$total_car = 5;
```

My customer order table

```
booked_car  start_date   end_date
1           2019-06-06   2019-06-07
2           2019-07-15   2019-07-18
1           2019-08-27   2019-09-03
```

I want to check total car has been booked by selected dated in my models

```
$this->db->select('SUM(total_car) AS booked_car');
$this->db->from('car_order');
$this->db->where('start_date >=', '2019-08-27');
$this->db->where('end_date  <=', '2019-09-03');
```

Result when search date same with in customer order table:

```
$booked_car = 1;
$avalaible car = 4 (get from $total_car - $booked_car);
```

But when I try to change date on start_date and end_date :

```
$this->db->select('SUM(total_car) AS booked_car');
$this->db->from('car_order');
$this->db->where('start_date >=', '2019-08-29');
$this->db->where('end_date  <=', '2019-09-05');
```

or

```
$this->db->where('start_date >=', '2019-08-31');
$this->db->where('end_date  <=', '2019-09-04');
```

Result :

```
$booked_car = 0;
$avalaible car = 5 (get from $total_car - $booked_car);
```

I think result should be :

```
$booked_car = 1;
$avalaible car = 4 (get from $total_car - $booked_car);
```

Because on '2019-08-29' or '2019-08-31' or any date as long as range between '2019-08-27' until '2019-09-03', car still booked base on booked_car table above.

How can I get correct results base on date in order table in my models.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should do this

```
$this->db->where('DATE(start_date) >=', datefordatabase('2019-08-29'));
$this->db->where('DATE(end_date)  <=', datefordatabase('2019-09-05'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise, unfortunatelly I have error message "function datefordatabase does not exist"

Comment: OO sorry I forgot this function you should write it in application/helpers/site_config                  function datefordatabase($input)
{
    $date = new DateTime($input);
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    return $date;
}

Comment: I have already follow your assistance, I get result $booked_car = 1; for all date selected, both inside date on row 3 in order table or other date. I try to check on 2019-09-10 until 2019-09-13, they also get $booked_car = 1; Thank you

Comment: Welcome you are free to ask question anytime, is my answer right?